# "Go doing something *to* somewhere"?

Tags: prepositions

Can I say "go doing something *to* somewhere"? For example, can I say

> He will go camping with you to the Porcupine Mountains.

With "to" I want to imply that they are going somewhere else (away from where we are).

Comment: You could also say 'go camping _in_ the Porcupine Mountains'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's grammatically correct, but which word is to be emphasized? With nothing emphasized it seems to need "...but not to the Gobi Desert" (or some place). "He will swim with you in the **sea**" seems to say, "...but not in a lake or a river".

Someone suggesting a camping or swimming trip usually says *where* they are thinking of going. No-one would allow a child to go without knowing where to, and it would be unusual for a parent to stipulate the locale of a trip someone else has been kind enough to offer the child!

If a child has been *begging* his father to take him, you might say, "He **will** go camping with you to the Porcupine Mountains," though, if it's a child, "He **will *take*** you camping to the Porcupine Mountains" might be expected.

Edit: As Kate Bunting says, "... **in** the Porcupine Mountains" is equally good - better, I think - and would be essential if they were walking!